# Perl - Changing a parent reference that is passed into a sub

Tags: perl

I am new to perl and couldn't find any info on my problem, so apologies in advance if this is a duplicate or I am completely out to lunch.

Actual question a little lower.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my @root = undef;
myfunc(\@root);

sub myfunc()
{
    my ($ptr_parent) = @_;
    print "root => ";
    print \@root;
    print "\n";
    print "ptr_parent => $ptr_parent\n";
    my @stuff = split(',', 'test1,test2,test3');
    $ptr_parent = \@stuff;
    print "stuff => ";
    print \@stuff;
    print "\n";
    print "root => ";
    print \@root;
    print "\n";
    print "ptr_parent => $ptr_parent\n";    
}
```

Not surprisingly my output is as follows:

```
root => ARRAY(0x7f903182e890)
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f903182e890)
stuff => ARRAY(0x7f9031838548)
root => ARRAY(0x7f903182e890)
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f9031838548)
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
root => ARRAY(0x7f903182e890)
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f903182e890)
stuff => ARRAY(0x7f9031838548)
root => ARRAY(0x7f9031838548)   <---- Note this changes.
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f9031838548)
```

So I have a suspicion that this is impossible to do like this because of scoping as I would imagine that the @stuff memory pointer gets released.

I feel like I could make @root a $root where it is a pointer to a pointer.  But I am stuck on how to write this.  The syntax for pointers is still not 100% in my head.

But the general requirement is that whatever list is generated in myfunc would need to survive in @root.  And I cannot modify @root directly from myfunc();

Thanks in advance. Let me know if I need to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, you need to use a reference, and pass a reference to that reference if you want to modify it from a different place.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my $root = [];
myfunc(\$root);

sub myfunc()
{
    my ($ptr_parent) = @_;
    print "root => ";
    print $root;
    print "\n";
    print "ptr_parent => $$ptr_parent\n";
    my @stuff = split(',', 'test1,test2,test3');
    $$ptr_parent = \@stuff;
    print "stuff => ";
    print \@stuff;
    print "\n";
    print "root => ";
    print $root;
    print "\n";
    print "ptr_parent => $$ptr_parent\n";
}
```

Output:

```
root => ARRAY(0x7f8143001ee8)
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f8143001ee8)
stuff => ARRAY(0x7f8143022ad8)
root => ARRAY(0x7f8143022ad8)
ptr_parent => ARRAY(0x7f8143022ad8)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `$ptr_parent` is a variable that holds a reference, and you are modifying the *variable*, not the *referent*. You need to use some dereference syntax if you want to modify the actual thing the reference points to. See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for an introduction and [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) for all the gory details.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my @arr;
dd(\@arr);

foo(\@arr);
dd(\@arr);

bar(\@arr);
dd(\@arr);

sub foo {
    my $aref = shift;
    @$aref = split(/,/, 'test1,test2,test3');  # notice the dereference
}

sub bar {
    my $aref = shift;
    $aref->[0] = 42;  # individual element dereference
    $aref->[1] = 'ponies';
}
```

Output:

```
[]
["test1", "test2", "test3"]
[42, "ponies", "test3"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl passes by reference, which means that changing the argument in the sub will change it in the caller too. But you're not modifying the argument (`$_[0]`); you're modifying a lexical variable (`$ptr_parent`).

All of the following will work with `myfunc($root)`:

```
# Create the object as needed, and pass it back explicitly on exit.
sub myfunc {
    my $parent = $_[0] // [];
    push @$parent, split(/,/, 'test1,test2,test3');
    $_[0] = $parent;
}

# Create the object, and pass it back explicitly up front.
sub myfunc {
    my $parent = shift //= [];
    push @$parent, split(/,/, 'test1,test2,test3');
}

# Create the object as needed by using a layer of indirection.
sub myfunc {
    my $parent_ref = \shift;
    push @{ $$parent_ref }, split(/,/, 'test1,test2,test3');
}
```

Or you could be less "magical" and pass a reference to `myfunc` (`myfunc(\$root)`):

```
sub myfunc {
    my $parent_ref = shift;
    push @{ $$parent_ref }, split(/,/, 'test1,test2,test3');
}
```

---

By the way, the prototype was incorrect. I fixed this issue by removing it.

Comment: I tried something like the first method, but couldn't get it.  I was definitely close though.   Thanks for the alternatives too.